# sudo dpkg --configure -a fixes apt-get file lockdown. Subsequent package install results in package removal interrupted earlier

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, updates, dpkg

I'm new to linux(ubuntu 18.04). Clicked installed on a couple of packages on ubuntu software center, and then removed a few. I'm not sure if this is the general case, but my ubuntu put those task in queue. While the last package was being installed, which I decided wasn't a priority at the time, I cancelled the installation, and proceeded to run an apt-get installation I needed urgently. This somehow messed up the process as ubuntu supposedly uses file lockdown, and I ended up terminating apt-get instance. Rebooted, and tried running the apt-get command to install the package, but it failed, with suggestion that I should run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` to correct the problem. I did, and the package was successfully installed, but the interesting part is, in-between the installation procedure, bash says Removing gnome-mines (1:3.28.0-1ubuntu1) ..., **sandwiched between installation** procedure. What's going on here? What exactly did `sudo dpkg --configure -a` do?

**Note**: I did earlier click remove on gnome-mines but I terminated the job before it even started. Did it somehow end up in task queue?

````
Get:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 gconf-service amd64 3.2.6-4ubuntu1 [2,036 B]
Fetched 62.8 MB in 8min 39s (121 kB/s)                                         
(Reading database ... 122669 files and directories currently installed.)```

Removing gnome-mines (1:3.28.0-1ubuntu1) ...

Selecting previously unselected package gconf2-common.
(Reading database ... 122183 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../gconf2-common_3.2.6-4ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking gconf2-common (3.2.6-4ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgconf-2-4:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libgconf-2-4_3.2.6-4ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgconf-2-4:amd64 (3.2.6-4ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package gconf-service-backend.
Preparing to unpack .../gconf-service-backend_3.2.6-4ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gconf-service-backend (3.2.6-4ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package gconf-service
````

Comment: I don't see any error messages in your output. What needs to be fixed at this point?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix There is no error. There's an anomaly. I'm just hoping somebody could explain package removal that happened in-between installation of another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answers your actual question, but I don't think it's what you want.

From [`man dpkg`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/dpkg.1.html)

> ```
>    --configure package...|-a|--pending
>           Configure a package which has been unpacked but not yet configured.
>           If -a or --pending is given instead of package, all
>           unpacked but unconfigured packages are configured.
> ```

ie. the command continued what you ^C aborted earlier.

*ps:  I find the reference `man` pages really helpful, along with tools such as `apropos` to find the page you need, or `info` etc they provide answers quick in my opinion*